# Найти все строки, если в строке могут быть экранированные "

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать регулярку, чтобы найти всё внутри `"`, учитывая что могут быть экранированные `"` внутри?

```
3;1"12345"32b -> 12345
"123\"4" -> 123\"4
```

Comment: У меня так вышло: /"((?:\\"|.)*?)"/g

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/249791/6944845

Answer (score 0):

Не скажу, что это оптимальное решение, более того, скорее всего оно ужасно (опыт работы с регулярными выражениями у меня минимален), но вроде бы работает...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

string s1 = R"(3;1"12345"32b)"; // -> 12345
string s2 = R"("123\"4")"; // -> 123\"4

string get(string s)
{
    regex inp(R"_("(([^"]*\"[^"]*|[^\"]*\\[^"][^\"]*|[^"]*)*)")_");
    cmatch data;
    if (regex_search(s.c_str(),data,inp))
    {
        return data[1];
    }
    return "";
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << get(s1) << endl;
    cout << get(s2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: У меня так вышло: /"((?:\\"|.)*?)"/

Comment: @Виктор Я правильно трактовал ваш вариант? https://ideone.com/GSWabR — просто мне не удалось его запустить.

Comment: Не открывается :(

Comment: Попробовал вставить два подряд `string s1 = R"(3;1"123\"\"45"32b)";` и ломается

Comment: А такая совсем уж жуть? Как в обновленном ответе? `regex inp(R"_("(([^"]*\"[^"]*|[^\"]*\\[^"][^\"]*|[^"]*)*)")_");`

Comment: @Виктор Ну тогда тут — http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ad1dd8e2e7b91e7 — как ваше решение правильно запустить?

Comment: У меня почему-то не получается заставить работать мою регулярку на С++. Выставлял тип regex inp(r, regex::ECMAScript) - не помогает. хотя на https://regex101.com/ всё норм :(( И с такими строками тоже работает: "123\"\"4".",23" 
3;1"12345"32b

Comment: Сама регулярка: string r = "\"((?:\\\\\"|.)*?)\""; regex inp(r, regex::ECMAScript);
 std::smatch match;
    if (regex_search(s,match,inp))